# Missing Project templates in XCode

Tags: xcode, macos

I have installed xcode 3.2 with iphone SDK. (without Mac OS 10.4 SDK). WHen i create new project i only got these options for Mac OS
-- Application
-- Framework and Library
-- Application plugin
-- System plugin
--Other

But a book named: Programming Object C 2.0. From which i am learning object C. Its showing XCode with these templates for Mac OS
--Application
--Audio Units
--Automater actions
--Bundles
--Command Line Utility
--dynamic library
--Framework
--Java
--Kernal Extensions
--Standard Apple plugin
--Static Library
--Other

I need the Command Line Utility template so that can create sample projects mentioned in book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Command Line Tool" is listed under the Application section...